# jquery.validate.js error on submitting the form via button click ,unable to set property settings of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form in C# mvc to make entry in database . I am using jquery 1.10.2 version.
When submitting the form via button click it gives error:
Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference

code at which error occurs:

---

jquery.validate.js

---

```
if ( validator.settings.rules ) {
        rules = $.validator.normalizeRule( validator.settings.rules[ 
                  element.name ] )
```

Comment: are you loading the form by ajax? if so, you need to parse it. And it should be a `<form>` element.

Comment: thanks.error was a nested form element.